# im trying to Write a program that accepts an integer n and prints the following picture with 2n – 1 rows:

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, rows

Write a program that accepts an integer n and prints the following picture with 2n – 1 rows:

```
1       X
2      XXX
3     XXXXX
………………………………………………
2n  XXXXXXXXX  (2n-1 times)
………………………………………………
      XXXXX
       XXX
```

this is the code that i have, but its not doing what its supposed to, what am i doing wrong? im thinking that i need to do something about the rows, but im not sure.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class a {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number: ");
        int n= input.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
            System.out.print('X');
            System.out.println();

        }

        {
            System.out.println("enter a number: ");
            int c= input.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<c;i++){
                for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
                    System.out.print('X');
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `its not doing what its supposed to` What IS it doing?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to print 2n-1 rows? not n rows?

Comment: In your main() method, I see an unneeded {} around the bottom half.

Comment: I had a programming assignment like this once.

Comment: thank you for fixing the picture

Comment: then you need to calculate 2n, you are using n, multiply with 2

Comment: @user3380761 That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a specific problem you can't solve by yourself, you need to provide us with as much information as you can. If you won't do the work to ask a good question, why should we do any work to help you answer it?

Comment: well i cant seem to figure out how to make it give the correct output

Comment: and why do you have the same function twice? copy & pase error?

Comment: and you need to print the spaces before the X:s also, it would be nice to have your output, and not need to compile the code.

Comment: Looks like the issue may be a result from not printing the spaces prior to printing `X`'s

Comment: Let me try one more time... What output is it currently giving, or at the very least, what is wrong with the output it is currently giving?

Answer (score 0):

your loop n times, not 2n-1 times. Also, your printing j X's, but you need to print 2n-1 X's.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a {
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number: ");
    int n= input.nextInt();
    int lines = 2*n-1;
    for(int i=1; i<=lines;i++) {
        int Xs = 2 * i - 1;
        int white = lines - Xs / 2;
        for(int j=0; j<white;j++) System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j=0; j<Xs; j++) System.out.print('X');
        for(int j=0; j<white;j++) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println();

    }
    for(int i=lines;i>=1;i--) {
        int Xs = 2*i-1;
        int white = lines - Xs / 2;
        for(int j=0; j<white;j++) System.out.print(" ");
        for(int j=0; j < Xs; j++) System.out.print("X");
        for(int j=0; j<white;j++) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println();
    }           
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scn.nextInt();
        String accumulator = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * (n - 1) + 1; i++)accumulator += "x";
        String space = "";
        String res = accumulator;
        while (accumulator.length() > 2) {
            accumulator = accumulator.substring(2);
            space += " ";
            res = space + accumulator + "\n" + res + "\n" + space + accumulator;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```